# Даны действительное число х и натуральное число n. Вычислить , не используя операцию возведения в степень

Tags: pascal

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Даны действительное число х и натуральное число n.
Вычислить , не используя операцию возведения в степень

Comment: жутко извиняюсь, а в чем вопрос собственно?))))

Comment: Ты ошибся сайтом. Тут не выполняют твои приказы.

Comment: @Эникейщик, хорошо сказано однако :)

Comment: цикл в помощь, число n натуральное

Comment: В чём проблема?

Answer (score 0):

подсказка - возведение числа `x` в натуральную степень `n` эквивалентно умножению числа `x` `n - 1` раз на само себя

это вроде как проходят где-то в начальной школе, даже странно что программирование вам раньше начали давать

таким образом вам нужен будет сделать цикл и использовать умножения и деления

Comment: Действительно странно, спасибо

Comment: Задача на сообразительность. Я бы лучше использовал свойства логарифмов и все средства, которые с ними связаны.

Comment: @DiD, ну это совсем халявно будет :) - задача по сути в одну строчку тогда решится

Answer (score 0):

Читай решил за вас задачу. Ответ будет `exp(n*log(exp(n*log(x))/2))`.

Проверить с разными значениями можно на форме ниже.

```js
const {log,exp}=Math;
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('input',()=>{
const x=parseFloat(document.getElementById('x').value);
const n=parseFloat(document.getElementById('n').value);
document.getElementById('e').value = x**n**2/2**n;
document.getElementById('l').value = exp(n*log(exp(n*log(x))/2));
});
```

```html
<form>
x = <input id="x" type="number" placeholder="2"/><br>
n = <input id="n" type="number" placeholder="3"/><br>
Вычисление степенью: <output id="e"></output><br>
Вычисление логарифмами: <output id="l"></output><br>
</form>
```